# Why is the number of Hamiltonian Cycles of n-octahedron equivalent to the number of Perfect Matching in specific family of Graphs?

Tags: graph-theory, convex-polytopes, perfect-matchings, hamiltonian-graphs, oeis

In [OEIS A003436](https://oeis.org/A003436), it is written that the number of inequivalent labeled Hamilton Cycles of an n-dimesnional [Octahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octahedron) is the same as the number of Perfect Matchings in a the complement of the [Cycle Graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_graph) on 2n vertices (i.e. a complete graph $K_{2n}$ without the cycle $C_{2n}$).

I can verify this relationship, but it seems very arbitrary to me. Unfortunatly, OEIS does not give further details.

> Why are these number of these two properties (inequivalent Hamiltonian Cycles and Perfect Matchings, respectively) equivalent in these two different objects (n-dimensional Octahedron and Complement of Cycle Graph $C_{2n}$)?

And hint or reference to the literature is very much apprechiated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The $n$-dimensional analogue of the octahedron is the complement of a perfect matching of its vertex set.  (Every vertex is joined to every other vertex except its antipode.)  If you take a Hamilton cycle in the $n$-dimensional octahedron then you can think of that as a labelling of the $2n$-cycle, and the non-edges of the $n$-octahedron give a perfect matching of the complement of this graph.

This paragraph was added in answer to Nicodean's comment below.  Label the vertices of the $n$-dimensional octahedron $1^+,1^-,...,n^+,n^-$, where the vertices $i^+$ and $i^-$ are antipodes.  A labelled Hamilton cycle in the octahedral graph is then exactly a $2n$-cycle made from the $2n$ symbols $i^+,i^-$ with the property that the symbols $i^+$ and $i^-$ are never adjacent.  Giving a perfect matching on the complement of a $2n$-cycle is the same as giving a matching of the elements of a $2n$-cycle so that adjacent elements are never matched.  To do this, I choose the symbols making up my matching to be the symbols $1^+,1^-,...,n^+,n^-$, where the symbols $i^+$ and $i^-$ are pairs that are matched.  The condition that adjacent symbols are never matched is exactly the same condition that I had on the $2n$-cycles that describe the Hamilton cycles in the $n$-octahedral graph.

One reason why this seems hard is that the matching sort of stays the same, while the $2n$-cycle whose complement it lives in is the thing that changes when you change the Hamilton cycle.

Comment: thank you for your insights about the complement graphs. I still don't understand why these numbers should be the same. I understand that the complement of octahedron-graph gives one perfect matching, and the complementary of the ($K_{2n}-C_{2n}$), so the $C_{2n}$ gives one Hamiltonian cycle. But i do not understand why, for example, the n=3-dimensional octahedron graph has 4 Hamilton cycles, while the $K_{6}-C_{6}$ graph has 4 perfect matchings. Could you please explain your intuitions a bit more, or refere to some relevant literature? thank you!